# PHPExcel output data twice

Tags: php, arrays, phpexcel

I'm working on something to show everything which is in the database in a simple excel file. And everything worked out fine but everything appears twice.

This is where the problem is I think:

```
$sql = "SELECT uei,first_name,last_name,email FROM " . $prefix . "users";
  foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $allRow[]) {
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($allRow, NULL, 'A2');
  }
```

**Solved by Mark Baker:**

```
$sql = "SELECT uei,first_name,last_name,email FROM " . $prefix . "users";
  foreach ($dbh->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $allRow) {
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($allRow, NULL, 'A2');
  }
```

Comment: Chances are that your query is returning a result row as an array with __both__ associative and enumerated keys.... look to the db library that you're using for the correct syntax to return one __or__ the other, but not both... e.g. if it's PDO you're using, look at PDO [setFetchMode()]( http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php) or passing a mode value in your query()

Comment: Thanks, but can't find anything. Weird thing is in a normal echo or something it's returning every variabele just once

Comment: Assuming you're using PDO, change `dbh->query($sql)` to `dbh->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: Also change `as $allRow[])` to `as $allRow)`

Comment: @MarkBaker How would this line turn out then?:
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $allRow[]) {
because I'm getting errors

Comment: `foreach ($dbh->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $allRow) {`

Comment: @MarkBaker Hero! _O_ Solved it!